# Подсчёт значения колонки таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE student_rating(            
    student_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    subject_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    exam1 NUMBER,
    exam2 NUMBER,
    final_exam NUMBER,
    average NUMBER
);
```

Надо значение колонки `average` автоматически посчитать формулой:

```
(exam1*0.3+exam2*0.3+final_exam*0.4)*100
```

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Посчитайте! Или у вас вопрос как это сделать? Какая часть задачи вызывает затруднения, что вы пробовали?

Comment: да чтобы average считывал автоматом

Comment: поставить триггер на события on insert or update на таблицу, где вычислять значение этого поля.

Comment: С триггером это будет самое неэффективное, подверженное ошибкам, решение для данной задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_rating_exam_calc
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF exam1,exam2, final_exam ON student_rating
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.average:= (:new.exam1*0.3+:new.exam2*0.3+:new.final_exam*0.4)*100;
END;
```

Comment: Если вы попробуете `update student_rating set average=0`, то какой будет результат?

Comment: Хех, average станет 0, конечно. Будем искать тогда и положительные стороны - остается возможность средний балл редактировать вручную.

Answer (score 10):

Если значение колонки можно посчитать на основе других данных той же таблицы, то ее хранить как данные не принято. Как минимум она занимает лишнее место на диске. Как максимум, в случае если надо будет поменять формулу расчета, придется изменять значения во всех записях.

Для решения данной проблемы в Oracle существуют [виртуальные колонки](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) их значения не хранятся, а вычисляются на лету:

```
CREATE TABLE student_rating(            
  student_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  subject_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  exam1 NUMBER,
  exam2 NUMBER,
  final_exam NUMBER,
  average NUMBER AS( (exam1*0.3+exam2*0.3+final_exam*0.4)*100 )
);
```

В случае если в будущем понадобится изменить формулу, вы можете всегда модифицировать колонку и более ни о чем не заботится:

```
ALTER TABLE student_rating MODIFY average NUMBER AS( (exam1*0.2+exam2*0.3+final_exam*0.4)*100 )
```

Answer (score 5):

Простое решение для всех версий - создайте таблицу без колонки `average`.
Потом создайте представление и пользуйтесь им где это необходимо. Вот так:

```
create or replace view view_student_rating as 
select 
    student_id as "Student Id", 
    subject_id as "Subject", 
    exam1 as "Exam 1", 
    exam2 as "Exam 2", 
    final_exam as "Final Exam",
    (exam1*0.3+exam2*0.3+final_exam*0.4)*100 as "Average" 
from student_rating
;
insert into student_rating values (1,'Math',10,20,30);
select * from view_student_rating;

Student Id Subject        Exam 1     Exam 2 Final Exam    Average
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Math               10         20         30       2100
```